# Django automatic database upload

Tags: django, database, django-rest-framework

I'm developing application with react-native and Django REST api.

what I want to do is to build a database using open api.

I made codeline for

I have implemented getting json format data through open api.

But I have no idea what to do next.

How can I put the data I have received into the relation table defined by Django model?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/ good luck.

Comment: sounds like you are trying to serialized model relations. Here is how to do it http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/